# Stripslashes and newline in variable in PHP

Tags: php, string

As I understand, stripslashes should not remove slash from newline character "\n". And all works fine, excepts situation, when I have a newline character in a variable.

```
$string = '\n\"';
echo stripslashes($string); // n"
```

But I need in the next output: `\n"`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Single quotes mean literal string as where the contents within double quotes gets parsed (which is what you want).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are mixing double and simple quotes

```
$bad = '\n\"';
$good = "\n\"";
```

Using single quote there is no escapement(appart ') also in single quote PHP won't replace PHP variables.

On the other hand the double quote permits using escaped sequence such as `\n`, `\t` etc...

You can review the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) and check the differences.

So you meant to write

```
$string = "\n\"";
echo stripslashes($string); // \n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside single quotes, `\n` does not translate to a newline. Use double quotes instead:

```
$string = "\n\"";
```

For a better understanding, your current code is equivalent to:

```
$unwanted_string = "\\n\\\""; // Will be printed as:  \n\"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using double quotes instead will solve your problem

```
$string = "\n\"";
```

Comment: WHy i have been given -ve :( :( ??

Comment: +1 to get it back at zero. I guess that you've been downvoted, because your answer is almost identical to mine, but posted 8 minutes later.